# Can we store iOS in app purchase receipt to our server

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, applet

I am developing an in app purchase app (auto renewal) and purchase/cancellation should effect on all platform (Android, iOS, Web).

My question is what is best way to keep track the latest status of the purchase. I know there is a way called server to server notification using web hook, but I am thinking can we store the receipt data to server and validate this receipt time to time with iTunes apis?

Does receipt data change over the updates on subscription or it is same even after changing the device?

All I want to validate it at server side, because there is a possibility that user can uninstall the app or not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, moreover server-to-server validation & observing is most preferable way recommended by Apple. They provided JSON API and accepts your server end-point to post any changes directly to server.

For details read [Choosing a Receipt Validation Technique](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/choosing_a_receipt_validation_technique) and related in topic.

The common start point is [In-App Purchase](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase)

Answer (score 2):

You can validate the receipts at server end. There are two options.

1. Enabling server to server notifications.
2. Store all receipts in your databases and verify it with server for latest update.

You need to use meta data from the receipt under key "latest_receipt" to get the latest update in the subscription.

Below is the link for reference.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH104-SW1

Initial receipt meta data does not change over the time. You can save initial receipt metadata in your database and use it for further updates like - renewal, cancellation, upgrade or downgrade, refund etc.